# Cors enabled in WCF but not working on live server

Tags: wcf, cors

I am hitting the post request to WCF service end point from my angular 7 application.   On localhost, the hit goes to WCF server but when i deploy the WCF application on server then Method 405 not allowed   Cors preflight error is showing in my console.     Even cors are enabled in WCF application.

What's the issue?  Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

In postman We are receiving following headers in response

Postman Response Header Received 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

When I publish the WCF Restful style service, I use the following solution to enable CORS.
Add the below global.asax file to my WCF service application project.

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, DELETE");

                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }

        }
}
```

Then I could use AJAX to send http request for resource, it works well.
I can’t locate your problem for sure, I will give you some advice if you could share more information related your solution.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: hey buddy , i used the same thing as you mention but it works locally ... and after deploy to the server it throws the error of CORS ...... saying it does not have http ok status.

Comment: Have you published the service using webhttpbinding and decorated the method with [webget]/[webinvoke]? Do you have used the other javascript client/tool to send an http request to verify the issue,Jquery/postman?

Comment: Yes , i am using angular 7 in front end to hit the http request on WCF services.

Comment: Angular 7 is running on localhost:4200 and when i try to hit , then error is happening .

Comment: If you use Postman to send request, Are you able to get the response properly?

Comment: i also tried with making a single html file and hit the ajax  request  using Jquery.

Comment: What is the error detail in the client browser? On my side, I construct a http get request. it works well. if necessary, I will post it in the reply.

Comment: Its working fine for GET method but not working for POST. Error in mozilla (Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at URL. (Reason: CORS preflight channel did not succeed).

Comment: My Post request also works, here is the sample code.
ngOnInit(){
    this.http.post(this.url,{"StringValue":"abc","BoolValue":true},{responseType: "json"}).subscribe((res:any)=>{
      console.log(res)
    })
}
The WCF service is the default project template.
One thing must be note that I use the below parameters to decorate the method for easily handling json parameter.
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);

Comment: [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
            UriTemplate = "Authenticate")]  I am using these attributes. Same code is working fine on my local but not working on server

Comment: It is weird. During the migration, do you have modified the service Uri in your code?  try to make a simple http post request to exclude the other errors.